# Visual Basic Check whether two images are the same or different

Tags: vb.net, image, compare, comparison, bmp

So I have a program which downloads images online and then stores them in files. But if two images have the same name, I have a piece of code which changes the file name to add a 1 to the end so that there are no errors. However, I was thinking it would be better to first check whether or not the images are the same before renaming them. And I am no way near good enough at VB as of yet to make my own image comparison code, so I looked on google and found this code but the thing is the code says that 2 identical images are different so? If anyone could have a look at the problem I would be hugely grateful.

Edit: Just for some further clarity I am comparing an image I already have stored in my folder with an image from the internet.

Re-Edit: I have found out that I have not correctly loaded one of the image variables if anybody knows what I need to change this would help? As I made the image variables the same to test and it worked fine.

```
Dim image1 As Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(picture)))
Dim image2 As Bitmap = CType(Image.FromFile(path + "\" + uname + ".png", True), Bitmap)
Dim a As Boolean = AreSameImage(image1, image2)
If a Then
    MsgBox("Identical image")
Else
    MsgBox("Different images")
End If

Public Function AreSameImage(ByVal I1 As Image, ByVal I2 As Image) As Boolean
    Dim BM1 As Bitmap = I1
    Dim BM2 As Bitmap = I2
    For X = 0 To BM1.Width - 1
        For y = 0 To BM2.Height - 1
            If BM1.GetPixel(X, y) <> BM2.GetPixel(X, y) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

Just out of curiosity if anyone knows how I could make it so that it checks the image against all the files in a certain folder - this would be really helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your picture like this

```
Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.co.il/Picture.jpg")
Dim stream As Stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
Dim img As Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
Dim image1 As Bitmap = New Bitmap(img)
```

Is the path for Image2 correct?

Comment: Didn't work for me but I found that I had already downloaded image1 before comparing them so I just did the same as I did for image2 so its fine now.